# No persister (NHibernate.MappingException) for ASubClass - Fluently

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Before asking here I read all post relative to the subject but I can't find any solution.

I removed all my domain complexity and I'm down to the following simple issue:

I have 2 class (in a domain file Domain.cs) :

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ASubClass : BaseClass
{
    public ASubClass() {}
    public virtual string prop { get; set; }
}
```

My Mapping is (In another file Mapping.cs):

```
public class BaseClassMap : ClassMap<BaseClass>
{
    public BaseClassMap ()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.HiLo("1000");
        Map(x => x.Name);
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("Type");
    }
}
public class ASubClassMap : SubclassMap<ASubClass>
{
    public ASubClassMap ()
    {
        Map(x => x.prop);
        DiscriminatorValue(1);
    }
}
```

First I let NHibernate create the DB for me :

```
var cfg = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
Fluently.Configure(cfg)
   .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
     .ConnectionString(connectionstring)
     .ShowSql())
     .Mappings(m => m
     .FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<BaseClass>()).BuildConfiguration();
new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false,true,false);
```

This works great, then my unit test is the following :
I build a session Factory within a Repository and use the Session/Transaction to try to save an empty SubClass:

```
var contract = new ASubClass();
IRepository<ASubClass> repository = new Repository<ASubClass>();
repository.Add(contract); >>> BUG HERE
```

This in fact bug on the line(inside the repo) : `session.Save(contract);`

I tried to copy/paste my Mapping.cs into Domain.cs or change the attribute of 
`.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<BaseClass>` to `.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<BaseClassMap>`

I also tried to change the hierarchy of subclass by removing the **Discriminator** and the
**DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn** keyword.

Didnt work so far.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You code actually works fine for me.

There must be something wrong with your configuration or your repository or how you use the configuration+repository within your unit tests. I mean, you create a new Repository, does this use the configuration you posted? 100% sure?

Are you using your cfg to build the `ISessionFactory` to be used by your repository? e.g.

```
var factory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
```

Maybe check that all mappings are in the same assembly, otherwise add both assemblies.

Comment: Well thanks, indeed I forgot to call .BuildConfiguration() and the end of my Repo in my unit test.
I would never have seen it without your comment. Thks.

Comment: @user3091460 does it answer your question? Cool, glad this works. please also mark that as answered, thx